# No tkinter package available

Tags: python, tkinter, rhel

While trying to import matplotlib on an RHEL Fedora system, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_example_images.py", line 9, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 194, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 108, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 79, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named Tkinter
```

Another question at https://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/How_to_install_Tkinter says I can use the following:

```
yum install tkinter
```

This should install a tkinter package for python 2 and python3, however, I then get the error

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                 | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                              | 2.3 kB     00:00     
No package tkinter available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

when I look at the yum packages I also don't see a tkinter package so it makes sense I'm getting this error.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.12

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.7, the Tkinter package name is `Tkinter` instead of the Python 3 `tkinter`. When I look at your error, it seems that your `matplotlib` is a Python 3 script.

If you have written `matplotlib` (at `/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py`) yourself (and it is written for Python 2.7), change line 6 from

```
from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
```

to

```
from six.moves import Tkinter as Tk
```

or a more version-friendly:

```
try:
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
    # print('Python 3')
except ImportError e:
    from six.moves import Tkinter as Tk
    # print 'Python 2.7'
```

If you haven't written `matplotlib` yourself, find a different install(er) for Python 2.7. If this doesn't work, use the fix above and report the issue by contacting the administrator of `matplotlib`.

Comment: I solved this by ignoring the problem and restarting it all with python 3.